# Color Word if in String

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to Color the word "Carrière" or "Carriere" If "carri" Exist in Cell.

To do this I Coded this :

```
For j = 1 To Len(.Cells(I, "AG"))
            If InStr(j, .Cells(I, "AG"), "carri", vbTextCompare) Then
                .Cells(I, "AG").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                count = count + 1

                j = InStr(j, .Cells(I, "AG"), "carri", vbTextCompare)


                .Cells(I, "AG").Characters(j, 8).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                Range(I & ":" & I).Rows.Copy
                Sheets("Carriere").Range("A" & lr).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                Sheets("Carriere").Range("A" & lr).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                lr = lr + 1

            End If
        Next j
```

Note that this `For` Is set in a loop with loop like below

```
    With ws
        rw = .Range("AG" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        For I = 5 To rw
         'HERE IS MY FOR LOOP

        Next I
 End With
```

**What is doing  this code** :

It **firstly** check if "carri" exists in cell, If "carri"exists then we will highlight the cell in yellow (**working**)

**Then** we would count the number of char before "carri"  this variable is called `j` once we counted it we will color the font in red for the `j` char (so the first letter of the word "carri" ( **c** ) and **7** more char. `.Cells(I, "AG").Characters(j, 8).Font.ColorIndex = 3`

But This is **not working** : Sometimes this work and sometimes it color something else ( Often the first word of the string)..

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: For starters, don't use `j` twice. And I don't think you need the `j` loop at all. `Instr` will just check the presence of the string.

Comment: You are incrementing count by one every time a match is found, but it appears you are not using that count anywhere else in your code.

Comment: I just deleted an answer, cause actually I got a bit confused. You are looping column AG and you want to color all the words carriere in these cells red? But then I see you copy paste these values and formats to another sheet. Would you be interested in my answer even though I left out the part where you copy/paste?

Comment: @Luuklag counr is used at the end of end with So I know How much time the word appear in a String.

Comment: @Dorian, you are also taking count with the `lr`variable, so your doing it twice ;)

Comment: @Luuklag Nop because `lr` will not be reseted for the next cells ^^ and `Count` is reseted each cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapted a piece of code I already had, maybe you can use it to draw some ideas from?

[image]

```
Option Compare Text

Sub ColorTag()

Dim Tags() As String, Tag As Long, X As Long, Y As Long, ChrPos As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For X = 5 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AG").End(xlUp).Row
        Tags() = Split(.Cells(X, "AG"), " ")
        For Tag = LBound(Tags) To UBound(Tags)
            If Tags(Tag) = "carrière" Or Tags(Tag) = "carriere" Then
                .Cells(X, "AG").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                Y = InStr(1, .Cells(X, "AG"), Tags(Tag))
                For ChrPos = Y To Y + Len(Tags(Tag)) - 1
                    .Cells(X, "AG").Characters(ChrPos, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                Next ChrPos
            End If
        Next Tag
    Next X
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I Solved my issue but this way was faster So i take this one, Thanks you